# Ending a while loop in command prompt

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is an excerpt from the [Competitive Programmer's Handbook](https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf) by Antti Laaksonen:

> If the amount of data is unknown, the following loop is useful:
>
> ```
> while (cin >> x) {
> // code
> }
> ```
>
> This loop reads elements from the input one after another, until
> there is no more data available in the input.

My question is how do we end such a loop in the command prompt, where the prompt takes one input at a time? By pressing enter, the prompt asks for new input and not terminating the input.

Edit: I have tried using ctrl + D/Z but I am getting this:
[image: Result]

Comment: ctrl-d on windows and ctrl-z on linux

Comment: You need to press enter after you press `ctrl`+`d` to actually send the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for that loop to end, `cin` needs to enter a failed state.  That will cause it to evaluate to `false` and stop the loop.  You have a couple ways you can do that.  First is to send bad input, which will cause `cin` to fail and end the loop.  Since you are excepting integers, you could just input a letter and that will cause it to break.

Another option is to send the EOF (end of file) signal to `cin`  You can do that using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (windows) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (linux) and the pressing enter.  `cin` will stop reading once it sees it has reachged the `EOF` and it will enter a failed state and cause the loop to end.

It should be noted that with both of these options that if you want to use `cin` again after you do this you will need to call `clear()` to remove the error flags and if you entered bad input, you will need to use `ignore()` to remove the bad input from the stream.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how do we end such a loop in the command prompt, where the prompt takes one input at a time?

Note that `cin >> x;` returns `cin`. This means when you write

```
while(cin >> x)
```

you do the `>>` operation into x and then **check** cin.

When the user enters an input whose `type` **differs** from the type of variable x, then this `while` loop will end automatically. This is because `cin` will not be in a valid state anymore and hence `cin >> x` will become `false` . Basically the loop ends when the state of the stream is set to failed. Like supplying a different type value or when EOF is encountered.

There is other way to end such a loop from inside the while block by using `break` .